# MongoDB: add element to an inner array of array with an object that contains field calculated on another field

Tags: mongodb

I have this document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("626c0440e1b4f9bb5568f542"),
"ap" : [ 
    {
        "ap_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000001"),
        "shop_prices" : [ 
            {
                "shop_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000097"),
                "price" : 102
            }
        ]
    }
],
"bc" : [ 
    {
        "bc_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000003"),
        "price" : 102
    }, 
    {
        "bc_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000004"),
        "price" : 104
    }
],
"stock_price" : 70
}
```

My need is to eventually add to ap.shop_prices an element if not exists with this structure:

```
{
    "shop_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000096"),
    "price" : 104
}
```

where the price is bc.price where bc.bc_id = ObjectId("000000000000000000000004")

This is my first (unsuccesfull) try:

```
updateMany(
   {
       "_id": {"$eq": ObjectId("626c0421e1b4f9bb5568f531")},
       "ap":{
           $elemMatch:{
                "ap_id":{$in:[ObjectId("000000000000000000000001")]},
                "shop_prices.shop_id":{$ne:ObjectId("000000000000000000000096")}
           }
       },
       "bc.bc_id": ObjectId("000000000000000000000003")
   },
   [
     {"$set": 
        {"ap.$.shop_prices": 
            {"$cond": 
                [{"$in": [ObjectId("000000000000000000000096"), "$ap.$.shop_prices.shop_id"]}, "$ap.$.shop_prices",
                    {"$concatArrays": 
                        ["$ap.$.shop_prices",
                            [{"shop_id": ObjectId("000000000000000000000096"), "price": ???}]
                        ]
                    }
                ]
             }
         }
      }
    ]
)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that:

- finding the bc related to your request using the $project
- using $map in the $set operator

This should be the solution:

```
    db.getCollection('test').update({
    "ap": {
        $elemMatch: {
            "ap_id":{$in:[ObjectId("000000000000000000000001")]},
            "shop_prices.shop_id":{$ne:ObjectId("000000000000000000000096")}
        }
    },
    "bc.bc_id": ObjectId("000000000000000000000004")
},
[
    {
        $project: {
            ap: 1, 
            bc: 1,
            stock_price: 1,
            current_bc: { 
                $arrayElemAt: [ {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$bc",
                        as: "curr_bc",
                        cond: {$eq: ["$$curr_bc.bc_id", ObjectId("000000000000000000000004")]}
                    }
                }, 0 ] 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "ap": {
                "$map": {
                    input: "$ap",
                    as: "current_ap",
                    in: {
                        $cond: [
                            {$eq: [ObjectId("000000000000000000000001"), "$$current_ap.ap_id"]}, 
                            {  
                                "$mergeObjects": [
                                    "$$current_ap",
                                    {"shop_prices": {$concatArrays: ["$$current_ap.shop_prices", [{"shop_id": ObjectId("000000000000000000000096"), "price": "$current_bc.price"}]]}}
                                ]
                            },
                            "$$current_ap"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```